# Upgrading Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft

I am fully aware that there are pages on the Gradle website that say how to upgrade, but only from 4.x and up.

I am trying to follow a [tutorial](https://blog.usejournal.com/a-beginners-guide-to-modding-minecraft-9a42536495f6) in making a simple 'my first' Minecraft mod. In it, you are told to install forge 1.7.10, which, from what I understand runs on Gradle 2.0.

In order for me to continue with the tutorial, after some digging, it appears that Gradle 2.0 is not compatible with JDK 12.0.2, but I'm not entirely sure how to solve this.

any help is much 'preciated.

Comment: Good luck managing to download the ancillary sources you need to make this work. Their URLs changed and no one knows what they are any more.

Comment: @Draco18s what's ancillary? I seem to have downloaded a later version (see my comment on one of the answers)

Comment: Forge downloads multiple files in order to set up a workspace. I don't remember which ones it were that moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending the answer from Chriki, you can change the gradle version in $projectroot/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
here you can change the path to point to already downloaded gradle-bin,
 something like this `(distributionUrl=../../../build/tools/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip)` 
or directly to gradle repository
    (e.g. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip`)

Comment: This seemed to work to an extent, but then I got a new error:

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'forge']
   > You must set the Minecraft Version!
      > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: I'll post it as a separate question, as my initial question has been answered

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid, you have a chicken and egg problem here: your JDK 12 requires a recent Gradle version ([at least 5.4](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/release-notes.html#support-for-jdk12), if I’m not mistaken). At the same time, the `forge` plugin that is used in your build doesn’t support Gradle 5, yet.

Maybe you can install and use JDK 11 instead? In that case you could work with Gradle 4 with which the `forge` plugin also seems to work. With my JDK 11 installation I could get the build to work as follows:

```
sed -i 's/gradle-2.0/gradle-4.10.3/' gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

This changes the Gradle wrapper version to 4.10.3 in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` (can also be done manually with a text editor). When I now run

```
./gradlew project
```

the build seems to generally work fine. It only complains: “You must set the Minecraft Version!” That’s a different matter, though.

Comment: Where am I meant to enter the 'sed' etc...? entering it in powershell returns an error

Comment: Forget about 'sed'. Like Chriki said, you can just as well change the file manually in a text editor. Also, you can run JDK 12 in older versions of Gradle just fine, but you have to fork the compilation process. If you need that, let us know and we can tell help you. But if JDK 11 works fine, just go with that. Good luck with the mod :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone here from Google, Minecraft Forge versions below 1.12 **DO NOT SUPPORT** any java version besides JDK8. You need to install JDK8.

The maximum version you can update your Gradle to is therefore 4.8.1, as any versions above that require JDK9.

Comment: I downgraded my Java version to 1.11, having upgraded the Gradle 4.10.3 (see the error in another comment) Are these still not compatible, causing the error?

Comment: Java 11 is not supported. The only version supported is JDK8, unless you are using Forge for Minecraft 1.14 @BenjaminWall

Comment: How do I change which version of the JDK gradle uses?

Comment: I'll just uninstall my other JDKs - probably easiest option

Comment: (Sorry for string of comments) Realised I could have just reassigned JAVA_HOME. Unfortunately, this still doesn't solve my issue in my most recent question. Please check it out