# Failed to apply plugin [id 'forge']

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312064/upgrading-gradle) My initial issue has been solved, but a new one came after.

Following the tutorial mentioned in it, having solved a few errors, I now get an error when I try to run .\gradlew tasks:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'forge']
   > You must set the Minecraft Version!
      > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

How do I set the Minecraft version? (1.7.10 in this instance)

Edit to include build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file, please?

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: If this requires a made mod, I haven't got that far yet.

Comment: Assuming this is a single-project build, the only `build.gradle` file is placed under the root of the project. If you're using the Kotlin DSL (instead of the Groovy DSL) then the file name will be `build.gradle.kts`. This file is where you would have added the necessary configuration to apply the Forge plugin. For more information about Gradle, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: build.gradle added.

Comment: Hmm. Well, the fact you have `minecraft { version = "...." }` would appear to discount what I thought might be the problem. I also can't find decent documentation for the plugin you're trying to use. In fact, as far as I can tell the GitHub repo doesn't appear to exist anymore. What happens if you follow this [Getting Started with Forge](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/#getting-started-with-forge) guide for MinecraftForge?

Comment: running through that I hit the same error message anytime I run .\gradlew ...

Comment: have you got any more ideas? I've been stuck for some time

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing the 'Recommended' version of Forge 1.7.10 instead of the 'Latest'. Simple fix really, although I've already hit another [wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580656/execution-failed-for-task-compilejava-issue-3-in-this-series).

Answer (score 7):

Good day.

For minecraft version 1.7.10.

I was with the same problem, searching the forum in Japanese.
this link [Forum](https://www.tntmodders.com/tutorial/env2-1710/)

You have to modify the repositories and dependencies of the build.gradle and change the gradle-wrapper.properties to version 5.6.4.

As indicated in this link [ForgeGradle-1.2](https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-1.2)

Contains an example to modify your build.gradle [example](https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-example)

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    maven {
        name = "forge"
        url = "https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
    }
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath ('com.anatawa12.forge:ForgeGradle:1.2-1.0.+') {
        changing = true
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip
```

[I made it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWaP.png)

Sorry, my English is very basic. I'm using a translator.

Comment: Hi there, I found a solution a long time ago but thank you for contributing for anyone who might have this problem in the future. And your English is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

pls update the plugin to latest one . For reference check this [link](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/) and  [link](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/28372-solved-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-forge-resource-gradlestartjava-not-found/).

also try deleting the .gradle folder in your User Home and run it again.

Comment: But don't I need Forge 1.7.10 in order to follow the tutorial for 1.7.10?

Comment: Also, neither of those links seem to be particularly helpful.

Comment: did you try `gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: also if none of the links are useful pls check whether the build.gradle has these [prerequisites](https://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-7/release/)

Comment: prerequisites seem to all be good, gradlew clean returns same error.

Comment: Any more help is much appreciated, I've been at this stage for too long.

Comment: in this case you need to update the forge version keeping same minecraft version. like this [link](https://pastebin.com/kmX4aHBL). the forge versions are specific to minecraft versions.