# Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. - Issue 3 in this series

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Before this question gets closed for already being asked, as far as I can see it is a vague and common error so this is different from other questions.

I fixed the error in my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331666/failed-to-apply-plugin-id-forge) by installing a slightly different version of Forge, but have now reached Step 5 of [this tutorial](https://blog.usejournal.com/a-beginners-guide-to-modding-minecraft-9a42536495f6). When I use .\gradlew build with the example mod, everything seems to work fine (although I cannot find the console output) But when I edit the mod to how the author describes, I get many errors.

The example mod:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        // some example code
        System.out.println("DIRT BLOCK >> "+Blocks.dirt.getUnlocalizedName());
    }
}
```

How I changed it, following the tutorial:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.1";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(amethystOre, "amethystOre");
    }

    private class ModBlock extends Block
    {
        public ModBlock(Material material, String blockName)
        {
            super(material);
            this.setBlockName(blockName);
            this.setBlockTextureName(MODID + ":" + blockName);
            this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run .\gradlew build, I get:

```
#################################################
         ForgeGradle 1.2-SNAPSHOT-fb514d3
  https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle
#################################################
               Powered by MCP unknown
             http://modcoderpack.com
         by: Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
         R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
#################################################
:compileApiJava UP-TO-DATE
:processApiResources UP-TO-DATE
:apiClasses UP-TO-DATE
:sourceMainJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    private class ModBlock extends Block
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Block
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        public ModBlock(Material material, String blockName)
                        ^
  symbol:   class Material
  location: class ExampleMod.ModBlock
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
        ^
  symbol:   class Block
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Material
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(amethystOre, "amethystOre");
        ^
  symbol:   variable GameRegistry
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setBlockName(blockName);
                ^
  symbol: method setBlockName(String)
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setBlockTextureName(MODID + ":" + blockName);
                ^
  symbol: method setBlockTextureName(String)
C:\Users\benji\MinecraftWorkspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable CreativeTabs
  location: class ExampleMod.ModBlock
8 errors
1 warning
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I don't know a whole lot about Java (I just started learning it) but I would assume that copying the tutorial character-for-character should result in an error-free program. Apparently not.

Looking at the error output on the compiler, the first error is 'The import net cannot be resolved' (line 3) I don't know why though.

Any help is much appreciated,
Ben

Comment: i think you are trying wrong import  try importing , import `net.minecraft.block.Block`

Comment: import also `net.minecraft.block.material.Material`. Additionally, use a real IDE and not notepad.

Comment: @Draco18s I am using Eclipse, what suggests I'm using notepad?

Comment: @SHASHISHEKHARBarnwal this works, thanks! (I'm sure I'll hit another error soon though)

Comment: @BenjaminWall Because Eclipse should yell at you about missing imports *long* before you get to running `gradlew build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comment)

Import are wrong. You should use `net.minecraft.*` not `net.minecraft.init.*` :

```java
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I created this almost 2 years ago, and I'm pretty sure someone ended up telling me I should be learning forge for 1.12 instead of 1.7.10 anyway. Still appreciated though.

Comment: xD I didn't think you will be back. I know it's late, but it's to help people that can have same issue. Also, it's to reduce the unanswered question. But if you have another question, I'm here. Finally, you can delete the question if you want

Comment: that's a very good point - in which case I will keep it up :) thanks for doing that